# How to write a handler chain executer (like express)?

Tags: javascript

I am learning about routing libraries like express and they all have a common

```js
export const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
  next()
}
```

So I am trying to make my own implementation of this to learn what's going on and I'm struggling a bit. Any good resources would also be appreciated

The problem I am specifically trying to solve is the following

```js
const executeHandlers = (handlers) => {
   // Run them in sequence
}

executeHandlers([
  next => { 
    console.log(1)
    next() 
  },
  next => { 
    console.log(2)
    next() 
  },
  next => { 
    console.log(3)
  }
])
```

I assume `next()` is the following handler wrapped in a function, but I am struggling to get it there.

Comment: Use a closure. Use recursion. Or `reduceRight` if you feel fancy.

Comment: @bergi Why `reduceRight()` and not `reduce()`? Middleware is applied in order, not in reversed order.

Comment: More basically, I don't know how to use reduce or reduceRight to solve this issue in the first place

Comment: @RoboRobok Try it and you'll see how the recursion works out

Comment: @DavidAlsh Then don't use them. Start with the recursive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version written with well-separated parts for clarity (and assuming you want to see `console.log(1)` get called before `console.log(2)`); see the comments for details:

```
const executeHandlers = (handlers) => {
    // Remember which handler we're on
    let i = 0;

    // This is the function we'll pass to the handlers
    function next() {
        // Get the handler to call, if any;
        // update the index of the one we're on
        const handler = handlers[i++];
        if (handler) {
            // This flag is specific to each function we pass to `handler`
            let called = false;
            handler(() => {
                // Prevent `handler` from calling this twice
                if (!called) {
                    called = true;
                    next();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Start the chain
    next();
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const executeHandlers = (handlers) => {
    // Remember which handler we're on
    let i = 0;
    
    // This is the function we'll pass to the handlers
    function next() {
        // Get the handler to call, if any;
        // update the index of the one we're on
        const handler = handlers[i++];
        if (handler) {
            // This flag is specific to each function we pass to `handler`
            let called = false;
            handler(() => {
                // Prevent `handler` from calling this twice
                if (!called) {
                    called = true;
                    next();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    // Start the chain
    next();
};

executeHandlers([
  next => { 
    console.log(1)
    next() 
  },
  next => { 
    console.log(2)
    next() 
  },
  next => { 
    console.log(3)
  }
]);
```

There are various spins you could put on that, like handling errors, passing a value from one handler to the next, taking a snapshot of the handlers chain before you start, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: …also, ensuring that each callback is called at most once (or everything flies apart).

Comment: @Bergi - I don't see why you couldn't queue the same function to be called twice. That would work fine with the above. Of course, depending on what this is being used for, you might not want that.

Comment: I mean if one of the middlewares accidentally calls its callback twice, the second call should do nothing (or throw an error). Remember when `async.mapSeries` didn't do these checks? Of course, if each middleware just returned a promise it would be much easier :-)